# Integrating filemanager in CKEditor error

Tags: javascript, php, ckeditor, file-manager

I'm trying to integrate filemanager (https://github.com/simogeo/Filemanager) in CKEditor and using php connector but browsing doesn't work (keeps loading forever) and if I try to upload a file I get this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Code' of null
```

This is filemanager.js

`var data = jQuery.parseJSON($('#uploadresponse').find('textarea').text());
            if (data['Code'] == 0) { ...`

the result from `$('#uploadresponse').find('textarea').text()` is empty.

As I said, I'm using PHP connector and default configs. I tried to access the files directly (not through ckeditor) putting in the browser `http://127.0.0.1/filemanager/index.html`

Comment: Isn't your properties called via object, not via array? `data.Code` instead of `data['Code']`

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I've extracted that part of the code from an older version (0.8). The most recent is minified so `b.Code` wouldn't make much sense to show here. You can access it through properties or array.